# Notion API [Beta]: Adding users to a workspace and changing their permissions

Tags: notion-api

Is there a way I add users to a workspace and change their permissions (edit, view, etc.)?
Does the current version of the API support this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, right now it doesn't matter if it's Internal or public integration, you can only give them edit permission.
[image]

Comment: Right, and how can this be achieved? I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Comment: Top right corner you have "Share"->"Invite" button where you add the integrations you created.